# Load JSON data into Angular 2 Component

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to load JSON hada into an Angular 2 Component, and I think I have found the way.

datoer.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DatoService { 

    dato: Array<any>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

        getDato() {
            return this.http.request('./datoer.json')
                 .map(res => res.json());
        }   
}
```

kalender.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValgteSkolerService } from '../valgteSkoler.service';
import { DatoService } from './datoer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'kalender',
    providers: [DatoService],
    templateUrl: 'app/kalendervisning/html/kalender.html'
})
export class KalenderComponent {

    private valgteSkoleRuter: Array<any>= [];
    //private datoer: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(private valgteSkolerService: ValgteSkolerService, private DatoService: DatoService) {
        this.datoer = this.DatoService.getDato();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.valgteSkolerService.hentLagretData();
      this.valgteSkoleRuter = this.valgteSkolerService.delteValgteSkoleRuter;
    }
```

My template is like:

```
<p *ngFor="let dato of datoer"> {{dato}}  </p>
```

My problem is the this.datoer above in the component. It says it does not exist on type KalenderComponent.
I have tried declaring it like this in the component:

```
private datoer: Array<any> = [];
```

But then it says that "Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable'.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http service, according to [Angular2 Http class docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html), returns an `observable` not an array with results, that's because it's made asynchronously. Therefore you must `subscribe` to the `observable` so you can feed your array when it gets `notified` (this happens when http request is complete).

For example:

```
public datoer: any[] = [];    
constructor(
    private valgteSkolerService: ValgteSkolerService,
    private DatoService: DatoService) {

    this.DatoService
        .getDato()
        .subscribe(datoer => { this.datoer = datoer; });    
}
```

Comment: "GET http://localhost:3000/datoer.json 404 (Not Found)". What can be wrong?

Comment: @MariusJ Your url can be wrong or mistyped or even the file doesn't exists. But that have nothing to do with the observable but with the HTTP request.

Comment: @MariusJ, have you figured this out?

Comment: I only have 1 problem; cell.id = this.datoer[this.j].dato; doesn't work. Cannot read property dato of undefined...

Comment: @MariusJ Where are you calling this from? on the component class? Could you add this piece of code on your question?

Comment: In the component yes, inside a for loop inside a function, so the "this.j" is the counter in the for loop. ".dato" is the name of the attribute in the json object. It's very much code if I'm going to post the whole function.

Comment: Does the this.datoer has values? Also, do you really need `this.j` inside a llog, why not only `j`?

Comment: Yes. If I write only this. datoer[this.j] it returns [object Object]. So I just added .dato to get the attribute, but I get the error. This.j is because the loop counter is declared outside the loop, as it's used in other functions as well.

Comment: console.log(datoer[this.j]) shows that at least that works. It's an object with 'dato: "2016-08-03"' inside.

Comment: @MariusJ so the loop is ok, the object that bring you the undefined value

Comment: It seems like the data is not loaded into the array in the beginning, but after x number (which differ each time) of executions of the page. I guess the data is not loaded asynchronously. You know how to fix?

Comment: It's a different problem which requires a different question. Could you please ask a new question describing this problem, and also don't forget to give a minimun testable portion of the problem you are facing